# Prometheus type conversion in metric_relabel_configs

Tags: prometheus

I tried with,

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [le]
    regex: '(.*)'
    replacement: $1 * 1000
    target_label: sla
```

this is storing label value as

```
service_apdex_expected_latency_seconds{instance="localhost:8085", job="playground", le="0.1", service="playground-service", sla="0.1 * 1000", uri="/products/{id}"}
```

Is there anyway I can convert the `string` to `int` and store?

Answer (score 0):

Labels are always "string", you can't convert them to "int".